# Postgres after update trigger on column does not reflect column value untill trigger completes

Tags: postgresql

I have a table teams as below

```
Name     pin    time
SAS      -1     12-02-2019
```

I have below trigger on it and the trigger function has pg_sleep function

```
CREATE TRIGGER loc_changer
    AFTER UPDATE OF pin ON teams
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE changes();



    CREATE  FUNCTION changes()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
IF NEW.pin <> '-1' THEN
 PERFORM pg_sleep(30);
 UPDATE teams SET pin = '-1' where old.name=new.name;
 END IF;
 RETURN NEW;
END;
$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

questions: during the trigger execution period I don't see the new column value in the Postgres database.

Comment: Is `name` the primary key? If you want to change the value of a column in the "current" row, use a `before` trigger and simply assign it: `new.pin := -1;` (and if you don't allow any other value in that column, then why store it at all?)

Comment: yes name is primary key.We wanted to have the new.pin value on the row only for a specific time before it is reverted .

Comment: To answer your question: yes this is expected behaviour. The new values are only visible once the transaction is committed. And it can only be committed once all triggers have finished and the UPDATE statement has been committed (either explicitly or implicitly).

Comment: yes i knew that but i was hoping that after update would serve purpose anyways thanks

Comment: The `after` only refers to the order of processing the individual UPDATE statement. It does not "break up" the atomic operation of a DML statement (which would be a horrible violation of the transactional concepts)

Comment: yep agreed!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

The final result is visible only when the transaction is complete (after the trigger execution).

You can't see intermediate result, ==> see [isolation level transation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/transaction-iso.html) for more information